# Using JavaScript to apply opacity to an div image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to use the `:before`selector for images, but found out that it's not possible, but I read that i can do it using javascript.

I'm not a pro at javascript and not exactly sure how to write the code.

This is the css being used

```
.carousel-cell.is-selected {
background: #ED2;
}

/* cell number */
img.carousel-cell:before{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: counter(gallery-cell);
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
}
```

It's being used in the carousel located here --> http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/YPezvR

Now what I want to accomplish is a `:before` and `:after` for the `carousel-cell` but for the images in the div.

I was trying to accomplish this with javascript.

```
/* cell number */
img.carousel-cell:before{
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
} 

/* cell number */
img.carousel-cell:after{
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Can anyone help me to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to give the carousel items not centered the `opacity: 0.5`?

Comment: Yes, I want the images not centered to have an opacity of 0.5 @ms_nitrogen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`css`

```
.carousel-cell {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.carousel-cell.is-selected {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The JS lib gives the focus item a class of `is-selected`, and in your css file, you can add those two bits of code and you should be a-okay without tossing in javascript.

Comment: Thank you, I should have known that but sometimes I forget things smh

Answer (score 0):

You can apply opacity to an img using javascript with an ID selector or other selectors, I will show you an example to apply opacity to img tag in div:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("myimgid").style.opacity="0.5";
</script>
<div>
  <img id="myimgid" src="img url" >
</div>
```

And you can add options to this js script (click, focus, blur and etc.) I showed basic way to apply opacity to img.

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel-cell.is-selected {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hey, this on its own doesn't make a great answer; explaining your answer would make it better (see the other answers posted here for example).